# Able to initially retrieve string from varbinary but not able to retrieve it again after setting it from ascii file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, bcp, varbinarymax

I have a `varbinary` column which I am able to retrieve with `bcp` to a file.

I then wish to update the `varbinary` column with changes I have made to said file.

I attempt to update this using T-SQL with `UPDATE`, `OPENROWSET` and `BULK` to import the file.

The initial retrieval with `bcp` gives me a file that is ASCII with CR LF.

But when I retrieve the column again after updating it (even if I don't change the file) I end up with jibberish (lot of questions marks and what not) and it's a `ISO-8859` text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators.

Initially I do the following:

Create a test table:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d da_dbname -U SomeDatabaseUsr -P SomePassVerd  -Q 'CREATE TABLE myTable(FileName nvarchar(60), FileType nvarchar(60), Document varbinary(max))'
```

Store the original in `myTable` so we can set it back and test again:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d datastore  -U SomeDatabaseUsr -P SomePassVerd  -Q 'INSERT INTO myTable (Filename, FileType, Document) VALUES (''ME_TBL_WITH_VARBIN'', ''DataBlob'', (SELECT varbincol FROM CONTENT_DATA WHERE ContentDataID=575757))'
```

Initial and 2nd retrieval after update is done with:

```
bcp  "SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), varbincol) FROM ME_TBL_WITH_VARBIN WHERE ID=57575" queryout C:\Users\me\Documents\test2.txt -USomeDatabaseUsr -PSomePassVerd -dda_dbname -S .\SQLINST -c"

Starting copy...

1 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
```

Which results in my file as expected.

And then using the same content pulled into

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\test2.txt
```

I try to update the same column to get the same file; but I do not.

How I update the record for the test:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d da_dbname -U SomeDatabaseUsr -P SomePassVerd  -Q 'UPDATE ME_TBL_WITH_VARBIN SET varbincol = ( SELECT a.*  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''C:\Users\me\Documents\test2.txt'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS a) WHERE ME_TBL_WITH_VARBIN.ID=57575'
```

How I test it (and so far changing nothing in the above statement has worked)?

If this results in 2 records it failed; if it results in 1 it succeeded:

TEST make sure they are both the same...if the same return 1.

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d da_dbname  -U SomeDatabaseUsr -P SomePassVerd  -Q 'SELECT count(*) FROM ((SELECT Document FROM myTable WHERE Filename = ''ME_TBL_WITH_VARBIN'') UNION (SELECT varbincol As Document FROM ME_TBL_WITH_VARBIN WHERE ID=575757)) AS Worked'"
```

I have tried several variations on "How I update the record" above such as using `SINGLE_BLOB`, `SINGLE_CLOB`, `SINGLE_NCLOB` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-large-object-data-with-openrowset-bulk-rowset-provider?view=sql-server-ver16))  and `CONVERT` but nothing seems to import the item as the same binary value.

Comment: I'm not sure `-c` is correct for bcp export, since you use nvarchar. Did you try using: `-w`

Comment: Why, out of interest, are you using an EoL version of SQL Server when it's free to update to a version that *is* supported?

Comment: Since this appears to be a **text file** - what's your reasoning for a `varbinary` column? Couldn't you just use a `nvarchar(max)` text column and store the data there? `varbinary` is typically intended for binary files - PDF's, image files etc. - not text files

Comment: @ThomA Somebody else's system, not my choice.

Comment: They *really* need to update then, @leeand00 . Like I said, there's no cost involved, as Express is free. There's a wealth of new tools available to you, one being far better CSV support with `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: Was the varbinary meant to hold nvarchar (UCS-2 or UTF-16) characters, iso-8859-1 or ASCII? Those are three completely different encodings. If you want the same varbinary data read back in then encoding really matters and the export and import processes need to be consistent in their handling.

Comment: Do you have a relatively small (undamaged) varbinary example you can post in the question so we can see what encoding it likely is?